# iOS 8 safari is crashing on picture upload

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, file-upload, camera

I have a web app I am building for smartphones.

The program is basically uploading a picture to the server and on the server analyzing the photo for a barcode and returning data about it to the page.

This code works fine on chrome (desktop debugging), android and iOS 8.3 on an iPod. It crashes the website on an iOS 8.3 iPhone

I would prefer not to scale down the image but I am having an issue on the server side with large data uploads.

[Question about server side issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30326054/959977)

```
$input[0].addEventListener('change', function photoTaken()
{
     if (this.files && this.files[0])
     {
          $.each(this.files, function readPhoto(key, file)
          {

               var img = new Image;
               img.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
               img.onload = function () 
               {
                    // Call to a library to resize the image and returns base64 string
                    var base64data = imageService.resizeStep(img, 500, 500);
                    scope.onPhotoCapture(base64data);



               };

               //This code was used before I started scaling down the image
               //var FR = new FileReader();
               //FR.onload = function (e) {
               //    var base64data = e.target.result;
               //    scope.onPhotoCapture(base64data);
               //};
               //FR.readAsDataURL(file);
         });                    
    }
}, false);
```

Update:

I believe the issue I am having is because Safari does not allocate enough space for large pictures and therefor crashes the page (or the whole program) when it runs out.

The issue only seems to be happening on phones where the camera has a high resolution.

Update 2:
Apple seems to have resolved this issue in Safari now.

Comment: why not use the built-in AVFoundation barcode reader (AVCaptureMetadataOutput) to read the barcodes on-device?

Comment: I have never heard of this. How would I use it from the webpage?

Comment: It is still reproducible for me on iPhone 6 and 6+ running Mobile Safari. I've filed a bug report with Apple (http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=5006458726907904)

Comment: Here's a [Codepen](http://codepen.io/ddgromit/pen/gpERyM?editors=101) if you want to try it out yourself.  I couldn't replicate it.